# Get reference to csproj.user in visual studio ENVDTE80

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm want to making changes to the a project in the solution explorer but I want this changes to be different from user to user, form what I've learned the best way to do this is to change `project.csproj.user` but I have no idea how to reference it.

The thing that I've got now is `DTE2.Solution.FindProjectItem` that returns a `ProjectItem` which in my case is the `project.csproj` can anyone tell me how I'm supposed to get a reference to `csproj.user` using the `DTE` interface.

I'm currently using VS2013

Comment: It is not a project item, just a file.  And usually doesn't exist.  It is stored in the same directory as the .csproj file so it shouldn't be hard to locate it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion I was hoping I would use the API provided by the SDK and not have to parse the file, that I know.